# jsoup select doesn't use the whole html?

Tags: java, android, html, networking, jsoup

What is my fault?

Android code:

```
ArrayList<String> plan_table = new ArrayList<>();
Element table = doc.select("table").get(1); //First Table: Untis Banner and School Data (Adress, etc.); Second Table: Plan -> So load second plan (index 1)
Elements rows = table.select("tr");
Log.i("SchollgymPlanThread","This are the rows: "+rows.toString());

for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) { //first row is the col names so skip it
   Element row = rows.get(i);
   Elements cols = row.select("td");
   //Log.i("SchollgymPlanThread", cols.get(0).text());
   plan_table.add(cols.get(0).text());
   if (Pattern.matches("^Klasse .*",cols.get(0).text())) {PlanParsed.put(cols.get(0).text(), new LinkedHashMap<String,List>()); current_class=cols.get(0).text();continue;}
            if (current_class != null) {
                List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i2 = 1; i2 < cols.size(); i2++) {
                    if (i2 == 2) {continue;} //If Lessons Hour , continue -> Lesson our will be put as key and not in the list
                    tmpList.add(cols.get(i2).text());
                }
                Log.i("SchollgymPlanThread", tmpList.toString());
                if (cols.size() < 2) {continue;}
                PlanParsed.get(current_class).put(cols.get(2).text(), tmpList); //ParsedPlan[current_class] = {lesson_hour:lesson_attributes}
            }

            //if ( row.className() == "list odd" ) {Log.i("SchollgymPlanThread","This is a class: "+cols.get(0).text());}
            //if (cols.get(7).text().equals("down")) {
            //    plan_table.add(cols.get(5).text());
            //}
```

I didn't insert the whole java code but this is where i get my problem... 
At Line 4 it prints out the html code with the td's and tr's but it stops suddenly. The last line of the output is:

```
<td cla
```

Is there anything wrong? I already checked the source website...

Comment: The logcat uses a buffer, probably you fill it. Try to print to a file and see if the output still gets cut in the middle.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks in advantage

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, please consider accepting the answer. If not, please rephrase your problem so that we may understand better how to help.

Comment: I can't try your solution because my computer currently doesn't work. I am writing this from my phone ;) Sure, I will accept the answer if it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

How do you read in the html with Jsoup? I ask, because you may hit the size limit of the loaded document. Jsoup limits to 1M, if not told otherwise via the [maxBodySize()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Request.html#maxBodySize--) method. So you may want to do this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("YOUR_URL").maxBodySize(0).get();
```

Comment: I use the URL Object and then i Pass ist to Jsoup. I will try the connect method